# Curse die rolls by dead taoists

Tags: ghost-stories

In Ghost Stories you can exorcise two ghosts at once if you are on a corner and there is a ghost on each space adjacent to you. I played a game where I successfully exorcised both of these ghosts but then had to roll the curse die for each of them. The first roll of the curse die caused me to lose a Qi which killed me. Do I still roll the second curse die? If it again comes up that I lose a Qi, what happens?

If I am already dead and there are ghosts on my board that cause me to roll the curse die on the Yin phase and I have to lose a Qi, what happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the situation of dying with an unresolved Curse die isn't addressed specifically in the rulebook, but your second question is!

From page 7 in the rulebook, under "Death of a Taoist"

> His board becomes possessed (see neutral board below) and the ghosts occupying 
>   it continue to act, despite the Taoist’s death. The steps 1 & 2 of the Yin phase must 
>   be played. The other players will have to suffer the effects and consequences of 
>   the ghosts on this board.

From page 10 in the rulebook, under "Possessed Board"

> A neutral board that has lost all Qi tokens 
>   is called "a possessed board", Its specific 
>   power cannot be used anymore through 
>   neutral power tokens. 
>   Any further loss of Qi points (i.e. board 
>   overrun or tormentor) must be endured by a player of your choice (the green 
>   Taoist’s power is ineffective if Qi loss is due to the curse die).

So if a player is dead and a curse die roll triggered by a ghost on the dead player's board causes a loss of 1 Qi, somebody else has to lose the Qi. Whether that somebody else must be decided before or after the roll is made is unclear. I would apply this ruling to the situation you present in your first question as well, the game doesn't want someone to weasel out of a curse die roll!